# unexpected element in running gradle

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently running a project on `Flutter 2.8.0` version, on debugging it, I'm experiencing this error below:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationManagerClient.java:10: warning: [deprecation] LocationProvider in android.location has been deprecated
import android.location.LocationProvider;
                       ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
C:\Users\user\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.8.0-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: warning: [deprecation] isFromMockProvider() in Location has been deprecated
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isFromMockProvider());
```

I tried to change the `Geolocation` latest version but leading to another error.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands

```
* flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get
```

Update the latest version of dependencies in ***pubspec.yaml*** file.

Comment: the error persisted

Comment: @oyelekeBlessing try to upgrade Flutter SDK . So that location issues of deprecation should go away .